Why did CSG add a NEG instruction?
The Commodore 65CE02, among many excellent additions, contains one I don't understand: the NEG instruction.
This certainly serves a purpose on machines without the equivalent of the SBC, like the PDP-8, but I'm not clear on why this might be useful enough on the 6502 to take up a slot in the opcode list.
Is there a use-case I'm missing?

Are you aware of any documentation describing how the NEG instruction interacts with flags?  How widely was the chip ever used or distributed?

Sometimes it's just "this seems handy, and it's really easy to do" (e.g., we already have microcode instructions to use 0 as one of the input operands, and to do subtraction. So why not?)

Opcode extensions, past the bare minimum are often rather according to taste and assumption then a result of problem analysis.

Although of course negation can be done with the existing SBC instruction, it looks like the equivalent sequence would be relatively cumbersome and slow, so a dedicated NEG A would be a significant optimization for a fairly common operation.
The SBC instruction would subtract memory from the accumulator, not the other way around.  So to negate, you'd need your operand in memory, and zero in the accumulator.  You also have to set the carry flag if you don't know that it is already set.
If I wanted to negate the value in the accumulator, I think I'd have to do something like the following, assuming I can make use of a scratch byte in the base page (equivalent of the 6502's zero page, say at address $42).  This listing is from the Virtual 6502 Assembler.  Cycle counts are from the 65CE02 datasheet
0000  85 42   STA $42   ; 3 cycles
0002  A9 00   LDA #$00  ; 2
0004  38      SEC       ; 1
0005  E5 42   SBC $42   ; 3

for a total of 7 bytes and 9 cycles.  If I can't spare a byte in the base page, and have to use an absolute addressing mode instead, then STA and SBC each need one more byte and one more cycle, for a total of 9 bytes and 11 cycles.  If my memory is slow and needs wait states, that adds more cycles as well.
On the other hand, NEG A is 1 byte and 2 cycles, and doesn't need to access memory at all.
I don't know the 6502 well, so maybe there are optimization tricks I've missed (perhaps making use of the stack?) but in any case it seems like a significant gain.

negate is equivalent to EOR #$ff / INC

@KelvinSherlock: Oh, very nice.  Want to post a separate answer?  (I guess that's 3 bytes, 3 cycles, so NEG A is still a slight improvement, but yes, not nearly so dramatic.)

Of course the 6502 doesn't have an increment accumulator but the 65c02 and 65ce02 do.

"Although of course negation can be done with the existing SBC instruction" - that's the opposite of the question. You need NEG on machines without SUB/SBC. But the 6502 has that. I did some basic searching through my ~100k of 6502 code and can't find a single example of someone doing a NEG using the pattern provided by @KelvinSherlock or your example. It just doesn't seem to serve a purpose on this CPU.

6502 doesn't have anINC accumulator instruction so maybe you're barking up the wrong tree.  Here is the 65c02 BBC Basic interpreter, which does EOR #$FF/INC 3 times.  It never once does SED, CLI, or SEI but that's not proof that they don't serve a purpose.

You would probably need to ask the 65ce02 designers to know for sure.  But...
The use case is: negating a number.  Sometimes people like to do that.
The 6502 was a simplified 6800.  The 6800 has a NEG instruction (as did the z80, the TMS9900, the 8086, the 68000, ...).  Perhaps a better question isn't why the 65ce02 added it but why the 6502 took it away.

Now fr that there is the standard 6500 answer: Drop everything that isn't substantially needed. Same way why there isn't ADD like on an 8080. It's really nice to not needing to care for carry before ADD or SUB, saves coding and cycles, but increases CPU size. 6500 was all about cutting cost.
